# How to set decimal point for price using TDbEdit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I set the decimal point in TDbEdit in Delphi.

I am new to delphi.

Please help to me how to set in tdbedit step by step.

Example:

```
66.33333
```

Expected result

```
66.33
```

Comment: What's the type of the underlying field ?

Comment: Isn't the database field object responsible for the edit mask?

Comment: float field for tdbedit

Comment: Set to that field `DisplayFormat` to `0.00`.

Comment: please explain to me where can i find the property?

Comment: Set the `Currency` property of the `TFloatField` to true in the Object Inspector.

Answer (score 5):

Click on your dataset then go to fields (click on the '...' button). From there click on the field name you want to change and set the DisplayFormat property to 0.00